# How many roots does $x^2-x$ have in $\mathbb Z_{10}[x]$ compared to $\mathbb Z_{11}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> How many roots does $x^2-x$ have in $\mathbb Z_{10}[x]$ compared to $\mathbb Z_{11}[x]$?

EDIT: I had a moment of clarity and everything makes sense now. I apologize for missing the obvious answers, it just wasn't clicking.

So $x^2-x=x(x-1)$ and in $\mathbb Z_{10}[x],$ we use the elements of $\mathbb Z_{10},$ i.e. $0, 1, ..., 9$ and plug into $x(x-1)$. We see that $0,1$ are roots since $0(0-1)=0$ and $1(1-1)=0$. Additonally $5(5-1)=5*4=20\equiv 0$ in $\mathbb Z_{10}$. Similarly $6(6-1)=6*5=30\equiv 0$ in $\mathbb Z_{10}$.

In $\mathbb Z_{11}$ we only get the two roots $0,1$ because 11 is prime and no combinations of the elements of $\mathbb Z_{11}$ gives us anything equivalent to zero in $\mathbb Z_{11}$.

Comment: Roots mod $10$ do not necessarily correspond to factors $x-h$.

Comment: Also you should easily be able to factorize this polynomial in an appropriate way in EVERY ring. Please don't just dump your homework here, try to think about it first on your own!

Comment: I know $x^2-x=x(x-1)$ and I should use $x=0$ or $x-1=0$, but I do not see how this gives me the number of roots in $\mathbb Z_{10}[x]$?

Comment: 11 is prime so $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ is a field, an in particular an integral domain. So if $x^2 - x = x(x-1) = 0$ then $x = 0$ or $x = 1$. In $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, there may be other solutions since $x(x-1)$ might be a multiple of 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The roots of $x^2-x$ in $\mathbb Z_{10}$ are $0,1,5,6$.

The roots of $x^2-x$ in $\mathbb Z_{11}$ are $0,1$.

You can do this by brute force, which is ok because there are just as few numbers to test.

Or:

For $\mathbb Z_{11}$, you can use that $11$ is prime.

For $\mathbb Z_{10}$, solving $x^2 \equiv x \bmod 10$ is equivalent to solving $x^2 \equiv x \bmod 2$ and $x^2 \equiv x \bmod 5$, and again these are easy because $2$ and $5$ are primes.

Comment: Hi, did you just use 0,1,...,9 and plug into $x^2-x$ to find these roots? And then 0,1,...,10 for $\mathbb Z_{11}[x]$

Comment: @KMath, yes, but for $11$ there are shortcuts as mentioned by gj255.

Comment: Careful: powers of $x$ greater than or equal to the characteristic of the field have lower degree than apparent.  Applying Fermat's little theorem, for instance, gives $x^2 - x \cong x - x \cong 0 \pmod{2}$, so *all* residues are roots.  Maybe that seems obvious, but how many roots does $x^{10} - x^5 \cong 0 \pmod{5}$ have?

Answer (score 1):

How to find such roots:

Case one, $\Bbb Z_{11}[x]$: $11$ is a prime number, so the only roots are the roots of the linear factors $x$ and $x-1$. Thus $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ are the only roots.

Case 2, $\Bbb Z_{10}[x]$: $10$ is *not* a prime. Thus there might be *additional* roots. Of course, $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ are still roots. However, we note that if we factor the polynomial as $x(x-1)$, then that could evaluate $0$ if one factor were even and one factor divisible by $5$, even if neither is $0$.

Since the only possibilities for divisible by $5$ are $5$ and $0$, and the case of $0$ was already covered with $x = 0$ and $x = 1$, it remains to see whether there are any solutions where one of the factors is $5$ and the other is even. It turns out that $x = 5$ and $x = 6$ both make this happen, and no others.

Answer (score 1):

Since $11$ is a prime, the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ is actually a field.  Since the characteristic of this field is $11$, Fermat's little theorem doesn't make $x^2 - x$ equivalent to a polynomial of lower degree, so there are the two obvious roots in this field: $[0]_{11}$ and $[1]_{11}$ (where the subscript indicates the modulus).

Since $10 = 5 \cdot 2$, $\mathbb{Z}_{10} \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_5$, with each summand a field (as in the prior paragraph).  The field $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is characteristic $2$, so we should apply Fermat's little theorem to discover $x^2 - x \cong x - x \cong 0 \pmod{2}$, so every equivalence class is a root modulo $2$: $[0]_2$ and $[1]_2$.  In the field $\mathbb{Z}_5$, the argument in the first paragraph holds and $x^2 - x = x(x-1)$ has the two obvious roots, $[0]_5$ and $[1]_5$.  Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we assemble the roots in each field into four roots in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$: $[0]_{10}$, $[5]_{10}$, $[6]_{10}$, and $[1]_{10}$.